# C# async ThreadStart and resume sync

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i want to start 6 Threads asynchronously, paused them and resume synchronously...

it should work like this one:

1. Thread 1 starting (thr1.start())
2. Thread 1 some progress (getting mac-adresses from txt-file, initializing com-objects)
3. Thread 1 paused (paused until all threads did the same as thread 1)
4. Thread 2 starting
5. Thread 2 some progress
6. Thread 2 paused
7. Thread 3 starting
8. Thread 3 some progress
9. Thread 3 paused
10. ...
11. after all 6 thread paused, they should resume all..

i tried with 6 simple boolean flags and wait until they are all `true` but thats quite a bit dirty...

any ideas?

EDIT (better visualization):

```
Thr1 | Initiliazing |waiting      |waiting      | Resuming
Thr2 | waiting      |Initiliazing |waiting      | Resuming
Thr3 | waiting      |waiting      |Initiliazing | Resuming
...
```

thanks and greetz,
flux

Comment: what is your problem domain - may be there is some diffenrt way to to resolve it

Comment: why not just perform the all 6 of the `some progress` in your main thread and then spawn additional threads?

Comment: because the `some progress` needs to be in each thread.. there are some messageqeue problems if i initilize my `some progress` objects in main

Comment: they cant be initiliazed at same time.. there are some dll-calls which cannot be at the same time.. so i need to wait... i edited the question

Comment: I think people are asking, "What work are your threads going to do?"

Comment: hi steve, nick answered my questions. thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want some sort of synchronization - a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) for each thread sounds likely, depending on your thread functions.

---

EDIT: Thanks for your updates - here's a basic example:

```
// initComplete is set by each worker thread to tell StartThreads to continue
//     with the next thread
//
// allComplete is set by StartThreads to tell the workers that they have all
//     initialized and that they may all resume


void StartThreads()
{
    var initComplete = new AutoResetEvent( false );
    var allComplete = new ManualResetEvent( false );

    var t1 = new Thread( () => ThreadProc( initComplete, allComplete ) );
    t1.Start();
    initComplete.WaitOne();

    var t2 = new Thread( () => ThreadProc( initComplete, allComplete ) );
    t2.Start();
    initComplete.WaitOne();

    // ...

    var t6 = new Thread( () => ThreadProc( initComplete, allComplete ) );
    t6.Start();
    initComplete.WaitOne();

    // allow all threads to continue
    allComplete.Set();
}


void ThreadProc( AutoResetEvent initComplete, WaitHandle allComplete )
{
    // do init

    initComplete.Set(); // signal init is complete on this thread

    allComplete.WaitOne(); // wait for signal that all threads are ready

    // resume all
}
```

Note that the `StartThreads` method will block while the threads initialize - this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: can you give me a small example? i have no idea how to realize it with this event :( greetings

Comment: Could you edit your question and give some idea of what your threads are doing - then I could give a more specific answer.

Comment: wow thanks ... looks like exactly what im looking for! i will try and give feedback! THANKS A LOT!

Comment: No problem - feel free to ask any other questions if you get stuck.